# Git branching model to a good project development

Tags: git-branch

I have been working on a project which is on git master branch.
As we are 3 developers work on this master branch and modify the same files, we get much conflicts.

To avoid these conflicts, do I need to create separate branches from the same master branch.

Please suggest me a good development procedure with git branching.

Answer (score 0):

Many shops use [the Git Flow model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).
[This page compares several Git Workflows](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Atlassian Git Workflow tutorial for centralized and decentralized model.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/